# how to install IBM java on linux

Tags: java, jre

I have downloaded jre pack from [IBM site](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/jdk/linux/download.html). downloaded file name is ibm-java-jre-7.1-3.1-i386-archive.bin. Not sure how to install this. I couldn't find instructions on site. I can't extract it or just run by double click. any idea how I proceed from here?

**EDIT**

I could install IBM java using package ibm-java-x86_64-sdk-7.1-3.1.bin. The way to run is using terminal by issuing the command 
./ibm-java-x86_64-sdk-7.1-3.1.bin and following graphical UI instructions.

Comment: Why does it have to be from IBM? And tell us your operating system.

Comment: I wanted to install IBM java for my testing purposes. I am on linux. anyway I could install IBM java with different installer. I will update my question. thanks